# Website is not centered in mobile device view

Tags: css, centering

I have a CSS problem with my responsive website.  So on desktop browsers all content is displayed good, but I notice problem on mobile devices. Here is screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

So on [my website](http://techmonegy.com) all the main content in mobile view is slightly moved to the right, so no blank consistent right blank space as left. You can see it on my screenshot link - subscription box is not centered, and similarly all content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the

```
.wrapper .sixteen.spans {
   width: 940px;   
   padding-left: 15px;}
}
```

at https://techmonegy.com/wp-content/themes/frisco/style.css

Those values are set for all media. You want to set the width to much lower values for mobile... or don't set it there at all.

Comment: no it's not...When you resize window you can see

`
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 768px)
.wrapper .sixteen.spans {
  width: 748px;
}`